# Could not set process working directory in Intellij Gradle project

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Building my Gradle project with Intellij often fails with the error "Could not set process working directory to 'C:\Users\username\IdeaProjects\project1'" and when this happens I see that the read-only attribute is set on the project1 directory and I have to open Windows security for the directory and allow myself full control, and then it will work for some time before it recurs again. If it is of any relevance the project was cloned from github.

The other error that occurs due to the same reason is that local changes won't be able to get committed, with the error message "Error updating changes: this operation must be run in a work tree", until I go back and restore permissions to the project directory.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you move the project folder to another place/drive? AFAIK, the IDE won't change the Windows security settings. Only Windows or security software does.